# Hide an element if there are no posts in a category

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function

Using Elementor in Wordpress to style a Website. A complete row gets the ID "newsticker" - there are posts from category newspicker displayed.

I want to hide this complete row (display: none) when there are no posts in this category. How is this possible, using the $get_terms function does not help :/

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the row in the Advanced tab -> Responsive dropdown -> Hide in all devices - desktop, tab, and mobile, in elementor. Or you can delete that row if it is useless. :)

Comment: yes i know with responsive settings. but the condition should be the amount of posts in a category, is it 0 then hide the row, is it 1 or more, then dont hide

Comment: There's a plugin called Premium addons for elementor, there I have seen the display one with different options

Answer (score 0):

If you can add style to your codes you can add a some style like below but it works only when your element is fully empty like this `.<div class="row"></div>`

```
.row:empty{
display: none;
}
```